# UTM to latitude-longitude, multiple post code UK

Tags: utm

We have some data like this:

```
Miles    postcode          X           Y

3.13     al 2 1         517972    203372

2.6      al 2 2         514612    203397
```

Here  X & Y is in UTM, we converted these values in Latitude & Longitude. For this lat-long we ploted POI's on map on the basis of distance specified in Miles. Because of overlapped area few poi's are getting mapped with multiple postcode.

Is it really possible ? since I am not familiar with UK postcodes, please tell me if there is something wrong i am doing.

I tried to search on Google, But did not find anything useful.

Any help is really appreciable.

Comment: I know that this must come late, but the UK lies in several UTM zones, so you should first determine the zone based on the postcode and then convert the Easting and Northing coordinates taking into account to which zone they belong to.